# Problema con objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un problema con el objeto JSON (jQuery mediante el metodo `$.post`) donde intento buscar en mi base de datos (mysql) mediante un input y rellenar los demás pos consulta. La cuestión es que me rellena dichos campos por unos segundos, con los datos correspondientes pero automaticamente se limpian.

Aquí dejo la función

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#buscar_empresa").click(function()
    {
        var postsend=$.post("buscar.php",{"cuit":$("#cuit").val()},"json");
        postsend.done(function(data))
        {
            if(data.razon=="")
            {
                $("#cuit").val("");
            }   
            else
            {
                $("#razon").val(data.razon);
                $("#cuit").val(data.cuit);
                $("#tel_empresa").val(data.telefono);
                $("#codigo").val(data.codigo);
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

---

Este seria el form que contiene los input a rellnear y el submit con id="buscar_empresa".

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
<form  name="form1" action="registro.php" method="POST">
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="razon" id="razon" size="32" placeholder="Razon social"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name= "buscar_empresa" id="buscar_empresa" value="Buscar"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cuit" id="cuit" size="32" placeholder="CUIT"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="tel_empresa" id="tel_empresa" size="32" placeholder="telefono/celular"/></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" size="32" placeholder="codigo"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <input style="float:left; margin-left:50px;" type="submit" name="continuar" value="Continuar sin registro"/>
    <input style="float:right; margin-right:50px;" type="submit" name="registrar" value="Registrar"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Cual JSON?, cual es el esquema de las tablas, que lenguaje, que intentas hacer? que tiene que ver el tiempo de ejecución? Wailo,  con todo respeto tu pregunta no se entiende nada. Por favor [edit] tu pregunta con la información necesaria o la pregunta será cerrada.

Comment: el input que hace la busqueda con que evento lo manejas, con keypress o onfocusout? explica eso porfa

Comment: @LuisFernando  $("#buscar_empresa").click .....

Comment: @WailoCARP, debes editar tu pregunta con el JSON y demás información que sea de utilidad para responder tu pregunta. Los comentarios son temporales. También lee: **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Me parece que si lo haces desde el evento click por eso te borra, porque si no escuentra coincidencias en la base de datos devuelve valores incorrectos.

Comment: @LuisFernando he chequeado desde console.log y los valores son correctos, de hecho rellena los input correctamente por milesimas de segundos. Nose donde esta el problema. Pense en usar timeout, pero no es algo elegante.

Comment: Segun el codigo que muestras tu problema no deberia ocurrir, por lo que podria ser la forma como armaste el form en el html, quizas estes enviando un submit sin querer.
Comparte el codigo hmtl del form donde esta el elmento con id=buscar_empresa